# How to run script on disconnect (node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a way to run a script when the user is disconnected. I know how to run a script when the user connects, but so far I have not found a way to run a script on disconnect. I think it should look something like this

```
var webserver = require("http");
var server = webserver.createServer(handleRequest);

    server.on("connection", function(param){

        console.log("user is visiting");

            param.on("disconnect", function(){
                console.log("user left");
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Http connections are closed so there is nothing to disconnect. You need to implement websocket. You can use socket.io for example, so you will have disconnect event which fires when a client is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

please look into this , hope it helps [server.close](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback)

> server.close([callback])#
>
> Added in: v0.1.90
> Stops the server from accepting new connections and keeps existing connections. This function is asynchronous, the server is finally closed when all connections are ended and the server emits a 'close' event. The optional callback will be called once the 'close' event occurs. Unlike that event, it will be called with an Error as its only argument if the server was not open when it was closed.